# Split string by commas that are not inside nested function invokation

Tags: string, scala, for-comprehension

I want to split function argument list by arguments.

An argument can be a function invocation like:

```
foo(...)
```

or any sequence of character. For instance:

```
"fisrt_arg, some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3()),  arg3), third_arg"
```

I want to get:

```
List("first_arg", "some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3())", "third_arg")
```

I implemented it as follows ([***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/UKFPza)):

```
private[this] def tokenizeArgumentList(argumentListExpression: String): List[String] = {
    var functionInvokationCounter = 0
    var previousArgumentPosition = 0
    var arguments: List[String] = List()

    for (i <- 0 until argumentListExpression.length)
      argumentListExpression.charAt(i) match {
        case '(' => functionInvokationCounter += 1
        case ')' =>
          if (functionInvokationCounter == 0)
            0
          else
            functionInvokationCounter -= 1
        case ',' if functionInvokationCounter == 0 =>
          arguments :+= argumentListExpression.substring(previousArgumentPosition, i).trim
          previousArgumentPosition = i + 1
        case _ =>
      }

    arguments :+= argumentListExpression.substring(previousArgumentPosition).trim
    arguments
}
```

It works, but looks ugly. 3 mutable variables and what I don't like most is this:

```
arguments :+= argumentListExpression.substring(previousArgumentPosition).trim
arguments
```

After iteration through the `argumentListExpression`'s is done we have to attach the last argument.

Can we refactor it in more functional way? Maybe `foldLeft` would help...?

Comment: You can definitely replace the `for` with a `foldLeft` and therefore be able to use `val` instead of `var`. Have your accumulator variable be `(functionInvokationCounter, previousArgumentPositions, arguments)`. I have another idea about the substrings, though.

Comment: @hoyland Can you tell the idea?

Comment: My thought is that rather than go characterwise, first split on `,` and combine elements of the resulting list as needed. Haven't gotten it worked out yet, though.

Comment: @hoyland Sounds interesting. Actually I have thought about it, but I decided to go another way. It looked complicated to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Recursion is divine. See - not a single var:

```
val s = "fisrt_arg, some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3()),  arg3), third_arg"

def tokenize (argumentlist: String): List[String] = {

    def tokenize (arglist: List[Char], sofar: String, inList: Int): List[String] = arglist match {
        case Nil => List (sofar)
        case '(' :: tail => tokenize (tail, sofar + '(', inList + 1)
        case ')' :: tail => tokenize (tail, sofar + ')', inList - 1)
        case ',' :: tail => if (inList > 0) {
                tokenize (tail, sofar + ',', inList)
            } else {
                sofar :: tokenize (tail, "", inList)
            }
        case c :: tail => tokenize (tail, sofar + c, inList)
    }
    tokenize (argumentlist.toList, "", 0)
}

tokenize (s)
```

The inList counts, how deep we are in the list.

If we woulnd't pass just the sofar-String, but the List-so-far too, we could make it tail-recursive, but it doesn't smell as if it might step too deep into functions with function as parameters, having functions as parameters, ...

Pitfall:

```
val s = "\"stringliteral w. (misleading brace\", f(a, b(c, d, e()), f), g"
```

You might like to apply some trimming in the end:

```
scala> val res = tokenize (s)
res: List[String] = List(fisrt_arg, " some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3()),  arg3)", " third_arg")

scala> res.mkString ("<", "><", ">")
res372: String = <fisrt_arg>< some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3()),  arg3)>< third_arg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, foldLeft is a possibility. It helps us removing mutable variables (which we try to avoid in Scala):

```
val string =
  "fisrt_arg, some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3()),  arg3), third_arg"

val result = (string :+ ',')
// The accumulator of foldLeft is a tuple  (previous splits,
// current split, nbr of opened parentheses)
  .foldLeft(List[String](), List[Char](), 0) {
    // Opening of parenthesis (might be the first opening or not) =>
    // increment nbr of opened parentheses to stop splitting:
    case ((splits, currSplit, openPar), '(') =>
      (splits, '(' :: currSplit, openPar + 1)
    // Closing of parenthesis (might bring us back to 0, in which case
    // we can start splitting again):
    case ((splits, currSplit, openPar), ')') =>
      (splits, ')' :: currSplit, openPar - 1)
    // ',' (split char) and if the nbr of opened parentheses is 0 =>
    // we can split!
    case ((splits, currSplit, 0), ',') =>
      (currSplit.reverse.mkString :: splits, Nil, 0)
    // In any other case, we just add the new char to the current split:
    case ((splits, currSplit, openPar), char) =>
      (splits, char :: currSplit, openPar)
  }
  ._1
  .reverse

result.foreach(println)
```

which returns

```
List("fisrt_arg", "some_foo(arg1, foo2(arg1, arg2, foo3())", "arg3"))
```

`foldLeft` will traverse a sequence (in our case a `List[Char]`) to process each Char individually to fill an "accumulator" (List[String] to be returned).

Notice the initialization `(string :+ ',')` which allows us to also include the last split into the list of splits. Otherwise, at the end of foldLeft, we would have the last split in the second item (List[Char]) of the accumulator tuple instead of it being included in the first (List[String]).

Comment: Looks a bit similar to Java's collector. Anyway it looks much more pretty.

Answer (score 3):

My idea works out to be essentially the same as the other answer, except operating on the "word" level. I do not know that I am a fan of modifying the last element of the list in this way--the idea of carrying a "current split" would be an alternative.

```
val result = string
  .split(",")
  .foldLeft((0, List[String]())) {
    case ((0, l), term) =>
      (term.count(_ == '(') - term.count(_ == ')'), (term :: l))
    case ((openCount, l), term) =>
      val finalElt = l.head
      (
        openCount + term.count(_ == '(') - term.count(_ == ')'),
        List(finalElt, term).mkString(",") :: l.tail)
  }
  ._2
  .reverse
```

Comment: Nice one, never thought of doing it this way. I took the liberty to propose an edit: 1) ._2 to extract the List[String] from the returned tuple. 2) using `::` instead of `:+` to prepend elements for performances.